# Which Access tier has to be chosen for the Azure blob storage to have a retention of 15 days.

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am thinking to store some of the data of my services in an Azure blob storage. I really require the retention of data for 15 days and I would access it rarely one file in a day. I may get max 5 MB of data per day to store.

I am not sure which Access tier  (Hot, cold, Archive) could be a better option in pricing wise.  I am not clear after reading the doc. Does any one give some pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really require the retention of data for 15 days and I would access it rarely one file in a day.

Azure storage offers three storage tiers for Blob object storage so that you can store your data most cost-effectively depending on how you use it.

The Azure hot storage tier is optimized for storing data that is **accessed frequently**.

The Azure cool storage tier is optimized for storing data that is **infrequently accessed** and **stored for at least 30 days**.

The Azure archive storage tier is optimized for storing data that is **rarely accessed** and **stored for at least 180 days** with flexible latency requirements (on the order of hours). The archive storage tier is only available at the blob level and not at the storage account level.

So according to your demand, I suggest that you could **choose cool Acces tier**.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers).